# jsf ui:repeat var is null in nested ui:repeat after ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, nullpointerexception, uirepeat

I have a problem with nested ui:repeat.

I have the next code:

```
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="cartItem" value="#{shoppingCartBean.shoppingCartElements}">
        ... //cartItem info

            <h:commandButton>
                <f:ajax listener="#{shoppingCartBean.changePortabilityEvent(cartItem)}"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            <ui:repeat var="discount" value="#{shoppingCartBean.getItemDiscounts(cartItem)}">
                ... //discounts info
            </ui:repeat>

        </ui:repeat>
    <h:form>
```

Well, when I click on the button, is like the ajax POST call is fired but the page is processed and the cartItem is null when the button is pressed, so it generates a NullPointerException.

My bean (shoppingCartBean) is SessionScope.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest?

Comment: jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar and jsf-impl-2.1.13-redhat-1 but is a big project, I think we can't change it easily...

Comment: Well, if you can't upgrade, then bite the bullet and use `<h:dataTable>` instead. True, it generates a HTML table which might not be what you need, but it doesn't expose that `<ui:repeat>` bug in older Mojarra versions.